# One page scroll wrong offset with floating menu bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an issue. Im using a one page design for a friend with a fixed floating menu  on the top. The problem I encounter is that when I click on a link it scrolls down but the offset is not right. Most the of time it scrolls down a little too much covering the content below the menu. What I am trying to achieve is that the scrolling stops at the div being exactly below my menu bar. The other issue is that somehow it wont scroll down when the space between two sections is too narrow. It tries but somehow only moves a few pixels then stops. I can imagine that both are related to the offset issue.

Im sorry, english is not my native language.

Here is what I got so far. A standard scrolling function with window.location.hash. The target are divs spread across the site.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var target = this.hash;
            var t = $(this.hash).offset().top;
            $('.wrapper').animate({
            scrollTop: t,
            }, 1000, function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
            });
        });
    });
```

You can see an example of the problem live: http://rolfvohs.com/

**What I tried so far** was using the add.class function to bind the div with an extra padding when a link is clicked. It does work in a way but creates an awkward space. I also tried placing the divs at different locations but that does not fix the job either, just messes it up further.

I would appreciate some insight.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.hash = target;
```

moves the scroll by default to the div position and you are setting offset top before the hash change so first its changes the offset after that it move to div location.

first try after removing the line "window.location.hash = target;" from the code
or 
move the "window.location.hash = target;" out side and above the "$('.wrapper').animate({})" it will work .